# REACT PROJECT STRUCTURE - where to put svg react components if they are shared across multiple components

Tags: reactjs

maybe in a separate folder in assets or common/Components?

I have seen SVGs put in separate folder in assets but they were svg files not components

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.